# A transition from CountVectorizer to TfidfTransformer in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization, tf-idf

I am processing a huge amount of text data in sklearn. First I need to vectorize the text context (word counts) and then perform a TfidfTransformer. I have the following code that doesn't seem to take the output from CountVectorizer to the input of TfidfTransformer.

```
TEXT = [data[i].values()[3] for i in range(len(data))]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0.01,max_df = 2.5, lowercase = False, stop_words = 'english')

X = vectorizer(TEXT)
transformer = TfidfTransformer(X)
X = transformer.fit_transform()
```

As I run this code, I obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nlpQ2.py", line 27, in <module>
X = vectorizer(TEXT)
TypeError: 'CountVectorizer' object is not callable
```

I thought I had vectorized the text and now it's in a matrix -- is there a transition step that I have missed? Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

This line

```
X = vectorizer(TEXT)
```

does not produce the output of the vectorizer (and this is the one raising the exception, it has nothing to do with TfIdf itself), you are supposed to call `fit_transform`. Furthermore, your next call is also wrong. You have to pass data as an argument to `fit_transform`, not to constructor.

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(TEXT)
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for a [*pipeline*](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), perhaps something like this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
])
```

or

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), TfidfTransformer())
```

On this pipeline, perform the regular operations (e.g., `fit`, `fit_transform`, and so forth).

See [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#example-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py) also.